# Insert timestamp via Kafka Connect Transformation

Tags: apache-kafka-connect

Is there a Kafka Connect transformation, which inserts a timestamp as a field?

**before:**

```
{
  "first": "second"
}
```

**after:**

```
{
  "first": "second",
  "foo": 1589889270
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the [`InsertField`](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/transforms/insertfield.html#insertfield) Single Message Transform will do this

```
…
  'transforms' = 'ExtractTimestamp',
  'transforms.ExtractTimestamp.type'= 'org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField$Value',
  'transforms.ExtractTimestamp.timestamp.field' = 'foo'
```

Comment: So per my example shouldn't it then be: `'transforms.ExtractTimestamp.timestamp.field' = 'foo'`?

Comment: I am not sure how this works, I tried it and get empty field.